# How to execute a script before login screen?

Tags: bash, startup, login-screen

I would like to know , how can I run scripts before the login screen.I mean My script should start running before login screen will appear.How can I achieve that?. I am the root user of that PC.

OS:Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your script in `/etc/rc.local`.